# malloc:what can "corrupt" allocated memory in Linux/Qt application (threads involved)?

Tags: c, multithreading, qt, gdb, ipc

*Dirty hacks at 05:00 AM. I have sinned, SO*, by passing pointer's address between same process's threads with FIFO:

```
total_buf = (char*)malloc(msize);
// ...
long addr = (long)&total_buf;
// ...
write(fifo, buf, 128);
```

After receiving pointer to total_buf in receiver thread, `void* pt = (void*)addr;char* tbuf = (char*)pt;` I noticed that buffer content changed, and that was clearly confirmed by examining memory content: `(gdb) x/1024xb tbuf`.

What are possible reasons for this to happen - in a context of multithreaded Qt+pure pthreads application's plugins trying to communicate directly? For some reason, I feel it's not some obvious garbage collection and afair, Linux threads are using shared process memory, so it's no address mismatch, and the pointer dereference looks alright too,.

Comment: Is it ensured that msize cant get zero?

Comment: I guess about aliasing in pointer casts you are familiar.

Comment: This is C?  I thought Qt was strictly C++.  Anyway it's not clear to me what "buf" is in that write() call, nor why you need the address of a pointer in a long variable.

Comment: Casting in this sense is wrong in the first place, but you're introducing **undefined bahavior** by casting the *address* of `total_buf` and saving it as a `long`. Further, if this is some function that is launching a thread and `total_buf` is a local variable, then the function exits while the thread is running, that address is long gone and no longer valid, thereby even more undefined behavior.

Comment: Yeah, you have sinned.  Get rid of the & and pass the pointer VALUE.  If you're going to do this repeatedly, the very next line after the fifo write should be another malloc, (and don't forget to free the bufs in the thread at the other end of the queue).

Comment: If you really need to store a pointer as integer, you'd better use `intptr_t` as it's guaranteed by the standard to be wide enough to hoöd an address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing here that you should try:

```
long addr = (long)total_buf; /* removed & */
```

...since you are later casting addr first to void* and then to a char*.  Your version has addr being the long version of a pointer to a pointer, not a long version of a pointer to the buffer.

Comment: Like @WhozCraig, I'm confused by the casting to long, but yes, the & has to go.  Typically, the fifo write is immediately followed by another malloc, so reseating total_buf for the next load of data.

Comment: I'm confused by the whole thing. The code snippet doesn't show where addr or total_buf are actually used.  Like I said, it's a guess.

Answer (score 2):

`addr` contains a `char **` and not a `char *`.
So that means that you are sending the address of a pointer variable, not the address of the buffer itself.
Later on in you thread code, you are casting the long back to `char *`, which should be `char **`. That's the reason the memory appears to be changed.

By the way: an address should be cast to a `size_t` and not a long.